# OpenJPA PersistenceException: java.lang.Boolean cannot be cast to java.lang.Integer

Tags: oracle, jpa, openjpa

In my Oracle database I have a column IS_ID of type NUMBER which I use for storing boolean values (0,1). The corresponding entity class declares the field:

```
@Column(name="IS_ID")
private Integer isId;
```

Fetching the entity class results in an exception being thrown:

```
org.apache.openjpa.persistence.PersistenceException: java.lang.Boolean cannot be cast to java.lang.Integer
```

While debugging the code I found out that the field is actually fetched as Boolean from the database. Why is this happening? My container is ServiceMix 5.3.0 with OpenJPA version 2.3.0

Comment: You should've mapped it to `Boolean` in the first place. Are you using `Boolean` anywhere in that field mapping? Getter and setter?

Comment: Nope. Getter and setter are Integer.

Comment: The only thing that comes to my mind is that OpenJPA concludes it is a `Boolean` because its name starts with `is` (btw, what is the name of getter method?). You can try changing the name to something else or making it `Boolean` instead of `Integer`.